# Google Tag Manager not collecting data when deployed to Vercel (Next js)

Tags: next.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, vercel

I am trying to use Google Tag Manager to collect event data (including page view) but it isn't feeding through to Google Analytics once its deployed to Vercel.

I have checked the following things:

1. GTM has a GA4 Configuration Tag with the measurement ID from GA
2. I have set up the GTM measurement ID as a public variable in env.local (and reflected this in Vercel)
3. T have added the script to _app.js
4. I have added the iframe to _document.js
5. Set up the tags required in GTM and published it
6. Using dev tools I have checked that the gtm script (with the correct reference) is fired in the Network tab
7. Also checked dataLayer in the Console tab is collecting the data expected

However, in spite of all of this I can't see any data in Google Analytics. Played around a bit yesterday expecting to see some today but nothing.

It seems to work on localhost and checking both in real time Vercel doesn't register a view but localhost does.

Previewing the Vercel URL from GTM does say its connected and I can view that in real time in GA when going this way, but if I go to the address directly it's not logging it. Checking 'Tag Coverage' on GTM also says the pages aren't connected.

Am I missing something? It seems to work in theory, just not in practice when visiting the Vercel address directly (as opposed to via GTM preview)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

I think I found an answer myself and it's rather basic. It seems a pop up blocker I had installed ('Pop up blocker for Chrome™ - Poper Blocker') was preventing it from firing. Disabling the extension seems to have done the job.